# common lisp: how can a macro define other methods/macros with programmatically generated names?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I realized that a certain section of my code consists of groups of methods that look similar (like I have multiple trios:  a helper function that gets called by two other functions meant for the programmer). I'm trying to write a macro that will define these three functions for me so that all I need to do is call the macro. But my attempt results in defuns and function calls that have quoted strings instead of the generated names as new symbols. What am I doing wrong?

Example (incorrect code)

```
(defmacro def-trio (base-name)
  (let 
    ((helper-name (format nil "helper-~a" base-name))
     (method-1 (format nil "~a-1" base-name))
     (method-2 (format nil "~a-2" base-name)))
    `(progn 
          (defun ,helper-name () 'helper-called)
          (defun ,method-1 () (,helper-name) '1-called)
          (defun ,method-2 () (,helper-name) '2-called))))
```

Now the following happens:

```
(def-trio my-trio)
```

==>

```
(PROGN (DEFUN "helper-MY-TRIO" () 'HELPER-CALLED)
       (DEFUN "MY-TRIO-1" () ("helper-MY-TRIO") '1-CALLED)
       (DEFUN "MY-TRIO-2" () ("helper-MY-TRIO") '2-CALLED))
```

Also, after I learn how to get this working, are there any extra gotcha's if I had this macro define other macros instead of other functions? I read [How do I write a macro-defining macro in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121145/how-do-i-write-a-macro-defining-macro-in-common-lisp) but I think my question is a little different because I'm asking about programmatically generated symbols/names. I'm open to being corrected though :) Thanks!

Comment: Please submit the 'macro define other macros' question as a separate post, as it isn't closely related.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

`` (defmacro def-trio (base-name)                                         ; changes:
  (let*                                                                ; 3.
    ((package (symbol-package base-name))                              ; 2.
     (helper-name (intern (format nil "HELPER-~a" base-name) package)) ; 1. 4.
     (method-1 (intern (format nil "~a-1" base-name) package))         ; 1.
     (method-2 (intern (format nil "~a-2" base-name) package)) )       ; 1.
    `(progn 
          (defun ,helper-name () 'helper-called)
          (defun ,method-1 () (,helper-name) '1-called)
          (defun ,method-2 () (,helper-name) '2-called) ))) ``

The following changes were made to your original definition -- the first change is the crucial one:

1. Interned each of computed symbol names into the same package as the base name using `(intern ... package)`.
2. Introduced the variable `package` which is bound to the package of the supplied `base-name` symbol.
3. Changed `let` to `let*` to allow the newly introduced variable `package` to be referenced in subsequent variables.
4. Changed the prefix of the helper method to upper case to match the convention for normal Lisp symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help! I got something working just before you posted but my code wasn't explicit about which package to use for the intern calls.

Answer (score 5):

**Use [`INTERN`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm) to turn the generated function name strings into symbols.**